# SQL counts based only one year

Tags: php, sql, date, count

I've tried several things but I can't find a way to filter this code to show only shows one year at a time. I've added WHERE statements, and statements like:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(show_date, '%Y') = 2013
```

But nothing seems to work, it just errors the code and shows nothing...

```
 $mostplayed = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tbl_shows.song_id, tbl_songs.song_name,    
 count(tbl_shows.song_id) as cnt, MID(song_name,1,35) as short_name, tbl_shows.show_date
 FROM tbl_shows LEFT JOIN tbl_songs 
 ON tbl_shows.song_id = tbl_songs.song_id
 GROUP by tbl_shows.song_id
 ORDER by count(tbl_shows.song_id) desc
 LIMIT 5");

  echo "<table style='float: left; height:150px; margin-right:30px;'>";
  echo "<tr style='background-color:transparent;'>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo "<h4>Most Played Songs:</h4>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mostplayed))

  {
  echo $row['short_name'];
  echo "  (" .  $row['cnt'].")</br>"; 
  }
  echo "</td></tr></table>";
```

The code itself returns the Song followed by a count in parentheses. Can anyone point me to how to only show one year at a time filtering out the data based on song_date year? Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

THE CODE ABOVE WORKS BUT GRABS ALL THE DATA FROM TWO YEARS...
THE CODE BELOW RETURNS NOTHING

```
SELECT tbl_shows.song_id, tbl_shows.show_date, tbl_songs.song_name, 
count(tbl_shows.song_id) as cnt, MID(song_name,1,35) as short_name
FROM tbl_shows LEFT JOIN tbl_songs WHERE show_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
ON tbl_shows.song_id = tbl_songs.song_id
GROUP by tbl_shows.song_id
ORDER by count(tbl_shows.song_id) desc
LIMIT 5
```

I'll pull together some data points shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** I believe your query should look like this

```sql
SELECT tbl_shows.song_id, 
       tbl_songs.song_name,    
       COUNT(tbl_shows.song_id) cnt, 
       MID(tbl_songs.song_name,1,35) short_name, 
       tbl_shows.show_date
  FROM tbl_shows RIGHT JOIN tbl_songs 
    ON tbl_shows.song_id = tbl_songs.song_id
   AND tbl_shows.show_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
 GROUP BY tbl_shows.song_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(tbl_shows.song_id) DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

Sample output:

```
| SONG_ID |   SONG_NAME | CNT |  SHORT_NAME |                    SHOW_DATE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     568 | Song Name D |   2 | Song Name D |  July, 19 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|      51 | Song Name A |   2 | Song Name A | April, 24 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|      13 | Song Name E |   1 | Song Name E |  July, 19 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|     368 | Song Name B |   1 | Song Name B |  July, 19 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|     168 | Song Name C |   1 | Song Name C |  June, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07ca8/3)** demo

Comment: sorry didn't work, my show_date is a DateTime format in a database, everything seems like it would work, any other ideas?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit what does *didn't work* mean? You get an error, you don't get any results, you get unexpected results? What is it? And IMHO it's about time for you to show table schema and sample data. Otherwise it'll be constant shooting in the dark.

Comment: Also you refer to two different columns in your question `show_date` and `song_date`. Which one are you actually trying to use and what table it belongs to?

Comment: One more thing. Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` in your query. Do you really have shows that refer (by song_id) to the songs that you don't have in your `tbl_songs` table? IMHO it should be either `RIGHT JOIN` or just `JOIN` (if you don't want to take into account songs that have not been played in any show).

Comment: just using show_date there is no song_date...I'll pull together my table and data, and I'm getting no results when I add a Where statement, but without the where it works fine just pulls all the data

Comment: I'm referring to a tbl_songs because I dont want to put song names over and over in the tbl_shows, song_id refers to the two tables and grabs the song_name based on song_id

Comment: THANK YOU ALL!! Turns out this query here worked. I guess I'm a little dangerous with coding it seemed my old code worked but not as well as I thought. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this and let me know if it's work or not?

YEAR(show_date)=2013

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work, I can't figure it out, something like this should work...

Comment: @Nilesh show my query as example and it's working why it is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

what user @user2510115 said should work. 
Here is a snapshot of sample data with 4 record 3 records of 2013 and 1 record of 2014

[image]

and here is the filtered data

[image]

Comment: I can see that would work, I'd done testing before and used that statement other places where I want to filter years is there something in my code that maybe already conflicting with the Where statement?

Comment: First of all do you have that where clause in the query? I don't see it in original post. Secondly, when you say it just errors the code; what is the exact error?

Comment: My original post doesn't have the Where statement in it you are correct. The code works fine but is grabbing all the data from two years, I want to add a Where to do one year at a time. When I add in a where clause and run the query nothing shows up.

Comment: I am not sure whats happening there. Can you try pulling all records with a YEAR column and then ordering/filtering them in the code by YEAR?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do date range queries is like this:

```
where yourfield >= the starting date
and yourfield < the day after the end date
```

The first reason is accuracy.  If your dates have time components, this query will still give the desired results.  The second is speed.  Using functions like

```
where DATE_FORMAT(show_date, '%Y') = 2013
```

or

```
where YEAR(show_date)=2013
```

is slow.